# Timing out when reverting VM Image from command line with VMRun.exe

Tags: virtualization, vmware-server

Every time I try to revert Virtual Machines from the command line on my server, with the machine powered ON or OFF, the vmrun.exe hits the timeout after about 1.5 minutes. Is there a way to work around this? Other than vSphere PowerCLI. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Need more details. Like Guest OS, .vmx file contents, status of CPU/RAM usage on host etc.

Comment: Windows XP Guest OS, CPU/RAM usage is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean reverting a snapshot?  PowerCLI lets you do the operation synchronously or asynchronously.  If the operation works via vCenter, but takes a long time, perhaps PowerCLI would help?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that PowerCLI can do it but this is happening in a script and the timeout is what is getting me. I would rather do it from cmd with vmrun.exe.